# Deserialize JSON to c# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

```
{"facet_counts":{
  "facet_queries":{},
  "facet_fields":{},
  "facet_dates":{},
  "facet_ranges":{
    "createdat":{
      "counts":[
        "2015-05-17T00:00:00Z",155,
        "2015-05-18T00:00:00Z",162,
        "2015-05-19T00:00:00Z",200,
        "2015-05-20T00:00:00Z",218,
        "2015-05-21T00:00:00Z",181,
        "2015-05-22T00:00:00Z",137],
      "gap":"+1DAY",
      "start":"2015-05-17T00:00:00Z",
      "end":"2015-05-23T00:00:00Z"}}}}
```

I am trying to deserialize the above json into my object but the counts part is not getting deserialized. My object is

```
public class FacetCounts
{
    public class Facet_Ranges
    {
        public class CreatedAt
        {
            public List<Counts> counts { get; set; }
            public class Counts
            {
                public Dictionary<string, int> count { get; set; }
            }
        }
        public CreatedAt createdat { get; set; }
    }
    public Facet_Ranges facet_ranges { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried removing the `public Dictionary<string, int> count { get; set; }` but still it fails. 
My deserialize code is

```
objObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacetCounts>(json);
```

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JSON2CSHARP](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Createdat
{
    public List<object> counts { get; set; }
    public string gap { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
}
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

```
public class FacetCounts
{
    public class Facet_Ranges
    {
        public class CreatedAt
        {
            public List<string> counts 
            { 
              get
              {
                return Counts
                  .SelectMany(pair => new[]{pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString()})
                  .ToList();
              }
              set
              {
                var pairs = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
                for (var i = 0; i < value.Length / 2; ++i)
                {
                  pairs[value[2*i]] = int.Parse(value[2*i+1]);
                }
                this.Counts = pairs;
              }
            }

            [JsonIgnore]
            public Dictionary<string, int> Counts {get;set;}
        }
        public CreatedAt createdat { get; set; }
    }
    public Facet_Ranges facet_ranges { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts mate but I found a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSon is invalid.
The error is the lack of braces around the complete JSon string {}

Here is a working JSon string:

```
{
"facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {},
    "facet_fields": {},
    "facet_dates": {},
    "facet_ranges": {
        "createdat": {
            "counts": [
                "2015-05-17T00:00:00Z",
                155,
                "2015-05-18T00:00:00Z",
                162,
                "2015-05-19T00:00:00Z",
                200,
                "2015-05-20T00:00:00Z",
                218,
                "2015-05-21T00:00:00Z",
                181,
                "2015-05-22T00:00:00Z",
                137
            ],
            "gap": "+1DAY",
            "start": "2015-05-17T00:00:00Z",
            "end": "2015-05-23T00:00:00Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used [JSon Lint](http://jsonlint.com) for validating your JSon, and fixed error by error.

I am not sure if your C# code is correct to Deserialize your JSon, so I would recommend you to use e.g. [JSon2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com) in order to create you JSon objects in C#. Then you can fix variable names, etc.

Comment: Apparently millions of responses where made while I ate breakfast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort mate, I validated my JSON on Json2Csharp and it gave me the proper output class.

Comment: Great! No problem. =)

Comment: Is this your answer? If so, please mark it as an answer. If not, do you need more help? =)

Answer (score 1):

Surround each item in counts with `{}`

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{},
    "facet_dates":{},
    "facet_ranges":{
        "createdat":{
            "counts":[
                {"2015-05-17T00:00:00Z",155},
                {"2015-05-18T00:00:00Z",162},
                {"2015-05-19T00:00:00Z",200},
                {"2015-05-20T00:00:00Z",218},
                {"2015-05-21T00:00:00Z",181},
                {"2015-05-22T00:00:00Z",137}],
        "gap":"+1DAY",
        "start":"2015-05-17T00:00:00Z",
        "end":"2015-05-23T00:00:00Z"}}}
```

Comment: but I am getting the json from external object, how can I modify the way it is returned?

Comment: You can't, but you should probably put that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't valid json - Your count objects need to be in {braces}.

FYI - You can also use json2csharp.com to auto-generate the c-sharp object to deserialize with, which would also highlight issues like this.

Comment: That is a valid JSON, the site which you mentioned, I put my code there and it gave me output. Thanks for the link.